# jfrog xray scan report integration with AzureDevops task

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

We are using Azuredevops Jfrog tasks to build our mvn/npm/gradle projectes and, using the below jfrog publish buildinfo and scan task to get the violation list. But as part of  the same pipleine , we are planning for automated way (either by script or azuredevops task) to create a report in xray by including the pipeline used "sourceRepo" and the build socope of the same pipleine.

Tried the XRAY api options, but failed to to generate it dynamically as part of the pipeline with these dynamic scopes.

```
  - task: JFrogPublishBuildInfo@1
    name: publishBInfo
    displayName: 'Publish Build Info to JFrog'
    condition: succeeded()
    inputs:
      artifactoryConnection: 'myserviceconnection'
      buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
      buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

  - task: JFrogBuildScan@1
    enabled: false
    name: xrayScan
    displayName: 'Security Scan'
    condition: succeeded()
    inputs:
      xrayConnection: 'myserviceconnection'
      buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
      buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
      allowFailBuild: true
      vuln: true
```